# ViewController and SegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I have `ViewCtrl1`, and `StartBtn`:

```
    -(IBAction)startbtn
{

ViewCtrl2 *vc2 = [[ViewCtrl2 alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:vc2 animated:YES];

}
```

I have also `ViewCtrl2`, `UISegmentedControl`, and `ExitBtn`:

```
 - (IBAction)exitIt {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If in `ViewCtrl2` i select `segment 2`, or `3`. When I press `ExitBtn`, will show `ViewCtrl1`, and if I press `StartBtn` from `ViewCtrl1`, my `ViewCtrl2` shows default selected segment, not changes that i made recently.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You creating new `vc2` each time and of course it shows default values. Initialise it once and reuse.